# How can I download Minecraft Java Edition on Windows 10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do i get minecraft on my windows 10 computer? i got a minecraft java edition giftcard and i redeemed it but i cant buy minecarft ive tried the play store but it trys to make me buy a minecraft package and my card doesnt have enough money for that and im really upset about thing not working! Ive tried watching and following along with many and many of tutorials and i tried to download it but it isnt letting me log into my microsoft account for minecraft. I NEED HELP!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to [this minecraft.net page](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/store/minecraft-java-edition) and follow directions. Once you click that link it's pretty self-explanatory.